# What screen sizes does (and will) Android honeycomb support?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, tablet

What screen sizes does (and will) Android honeycomb support?

When I try anything other than WXGA on the emulators, even the system apps and home-screen look odd.  Should I assume that Honeycomb does not, and will not, support anything other than tablets?

Answer (score 0):

> What screen sizes does (and will) Android honeycomb support?

"Will" is impossible to answer, as nobody can predict the future with any accuracy.

"Does" is impossible to answer in the way you appear to be expecting (resolution).

> Should I assume that Honeycomb does not, and will not, support anything other than tablets?

Since Google has indicated this repeatedly in 2011, I think that it is a safe assumption.

Note that Android 3.2 added support for tablets in the 7" range in addition to the 10" range. Resolutions are up to the device manufacturer. That being said, one likely resolution for 7" tablets is 1024x600.

The Android emulator only really supports WXGA for Android 3.x at this time, AFAIK -- at least, that's the only supported emulator skin.

Also note that Honeycomb concepts are likely to appear in Ice Cream Sandwich, which is rumored to be released later this year.